# ¿Cómo comparar una línea de texto con una palabra en Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

tengo un archivo con la siguiente estructura

```
hola como estas 
esto es una prueba
todo comenzo a las 2
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que se compare cada línea de mi archivo y en donde encuentre la palabra **prueba** la guarde en una variable. Intenté esto pero no me sale lo que pretendo:

```
while read line; do
   if [ echo -e "$line\n" = 'prueba' ]; then
     $variable=echo -e "$line\n";
     echo "$variable esta linea tiene la palabra prueba"
done < archivo.txt
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer con el resultado? ¿Puede aparecer más de una vez? Nótese que dices `$variable=echo -e "$line\n";` y es incorrecto en varias cosas: las variables se definen sin el dólar delante. Además, si quieres guardar el resultado de un comando debes decir `var=$(comando)`.

Comment: gracias por el aporte quería  automatizar unos comandos  queria plasmar una idea  soy principiante me fallan algunos detalles  aun

Comment: ¿Pero realmente necesitas extraer la línea completa y guardarla? ¿Y si hay más de una? Porque un simple `linea=$(awk '/prueba/' fichero)` seguramente ya hace todo lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:
con la funcion `grep` que busca texto en una cadena

```
#!/bin/bash
buscar(){
    nl=0;
    while read -r line
    do
        nl=$((nl+=1))
        if [[ $(echo "$line" | grep "$1") != "" ]];
        then
             echo "la linea:${nl} -> texto: ${line}"
        fi
    done < archivo.txt

}

buscar "prueba"
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!